# How can i search a company's name by a specified product on freebase?

Tags: freebase, mql

I tried a MQL to search "Microsoft Corporation" as below:

```
[{


  "name": "Windows Vista Home Basic",

  "type": "/business/consumer_product",

  "/business/consumer_product/company": null

}]
```

It's showed:

```
{

  "result": [{

    "/business/consumer_product/company": null,

    "type": "/business/consumer_product",

    "name": "Windows Vista Home Basic"

  }]

}
```

Obviously the "/business/consumer_product/company" is one property of the "product", but it failed.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it worked perfectly.  The linked node in this case, though, is a mediator with links to a company, a From date, and a To date.  As such, the mediator node doesn't have a name, ie it's null.

Try this query to fetch the next node, one hop further away:

```
[{
  "name": "Windows Vista Home Basic",
  "type": "/business/consumer_product",
  "/business/consumer_product/company": {
    "/business/company_product_relationship/company": {
      "id": null,
      "name": null
    }
  }
}]
```